# Implicitwait not waiting for the specified duration in the code mentioned below

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium webdriver have to wait for 30 seconds and 5 seconds where it's mentioned in the code. But noticed that webdriver is skipping that. What's the reason and how can i make the webdriver wait.

```
System.out.println("Before 5"+date.toString());

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

System.out.println("After 5"+date.toString());
```

Link to the complete code can be found here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4SgyzyvwKhiUk9KVldTa2ZGUkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please let me know on what basis you are saying that it is not waiting? Is it throwing 'NoSuchElememt' or element not found execption without waiting for 5 secs?

Comment: no error. Figured out by printing the time before wait and after wait.

Comment: Please see the posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit wait doesn't work like the normal `Thread.sleep()` where you put `5s` time and your main thread gets halted and wait for 5 seconds.

It will work with the `WebDriver Instance` where it will wait for a particular element on a web page to appear for time mentioned in the wait. If there are no elements to identify i.e. element is already loaded in dom, your implicit wait won't wait for that period of time.

So when you say:-

```
System.out.println("Before 5"+date.toString());
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("After 5"+date.toString());
```

It won't show you the time difference of 5 seconds.

If there would have been any element which isn't loaded in dom it would have wait for 5 seconds.

```
System.out.println("Before 5"+date.toString());
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).sendKeys("Some Text")
System.out.println("After 5"+date.toString());  |
                                                |------- Here if the element isn't loaded in dom, then webdriver would wait for 5 seconds.
```

More information on [Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: Hi @pArAs, thanks for the answer. Have a suggestion. Recently i got a comment from SO asking not to refer to external sites for answering. If the the external page is removed in future, it may be difficult for the users to get proper answer while referring the thread. So recommended to place the useful content in the answer itself.

Comment: Thats why I've modified my answer to explain with 2 code examples. I just put one more reference to understand. Rather I would update the reference to main `Selenium` website.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait 5s.You can try:

1. `Thread.sleep(5000);`
2. `(new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
                   .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>()`